# How do I prevent a program from consuming all available memory?

Tags: windows-7, memory

Sometimes, a program will decide to take up all available physical memory (8 GB total) on my computer, freezing Windows in only a few seconds.

Even a simple C++ program (`for(;;) new long long int;`) compiled with MinGW will consume all memory and lock up Windows in a fairly short amount of time. (In fact, I've tested this same program on two different computers with Windows 7 x64 with the same result.)

How can I have a memory-intensive program suspended or killed right before Windows reaches 99% memory usage, thus averting a crash?

Comment: See [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7292/2401) on SoftwareRecs.SE

Comment: @Cornelius Looks useful, but you have to add a rule for each program.